# How to describe domains in AWS SimpleDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

Is it possible to do an SQL-like `describe tables` statement with AWS SimpleDB and if so, what's the syntax. The same for `show tables` or whatever the equivalent of that might be.

If you know of a resource that explains all of this, please tell me where it is, because I can't find the information I'm looking for.

**Edit**

I came across a SimpleDB query that someone else wrote in something that I'm working on. It looks something like `select A, B, C from MyDomain where D = 'SomeVal'`.

I didn't create the database so I don't know if this SimpleDB has the data that I need. I'd like to find out just the column names that `MyDomain` contains/accepts. Is that even possible?

**Solution**

Oh, I suppose I could just `select * from MyDomain limit 1` and then print out then print out each from `getName()` in the attribute list.

Comment: Trouble with your solution is that different items can have different attributes...

Answer (score 0):

There is noting similar to `describe tables` in Amazon SimpleDB.  `Amazon SimpleDB` concept is different from `traditional database`. `Amazon SimpleDB` is `non structure database service`. `Amazon SimpleDB` requires `no schema`, automatically indexes your data and provides a simple API for storage and access. `Amazon SimpleDB provides flexibility to add new attributes that only applies to certain rows. Therefore, each row may have different-different attributes`. To learn more about service - [doc](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/simpledb/) & [related links](http://www.packtpub.com/article/amazon-simpledb-versus-rdbms)